# SQL Syntax for NOT NULL cells

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am trying to query two different things:

1) cells with an empty value

`WHERE (user_id = '$userId' AND sub_id = '')`

2) cells with a value

`WHERE (user_id = '$userId' AND sub_id IS NOT NULL)`

The former works fine but the latter calls every cell, regardless of whether it has values in it or not.

Is there another way?

database looks something like this:

```
user_id --- sub_id

---1---45---

---4--- ---

---78---34---
```

I can call user 4's info, but not call user 1 or user 78, who have values in sub_id

Comment: I believe there is a whitespace in that column, you need to check that

Comment: @Satya, that might explain why an `is null` wouldn't retrieve 4 but I'm not sure how it explains why `is not null` doesn't retrieve 1 or 78.

Comment: @paxdiablo. he says earlier that the second query returns all the rows. I believe he is talking about the first query at the end saying he can get user 4, but not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first query returns the user_id = 4, it means that row has sub_id = "". If you don't want that in your second query try changing it to:

`WHERE user_id = '$userId' AND sub_id IS NOT NULL AND sub_id != ""`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. In theory could I just remove the IS NOT NULL clause from the second query altogether?

Comment: If everywhere you are expected to have null values you have "", then it would work without the IS NOT NULL.